# DateTime.DayOfWeek translation from VB.NET to C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, enums

i've a simple vb.net code snippet here:

```
While pStartDay.DayOfWeek <> 1
    pStartDay = pStartDay.AddDays(-1)
End While

While pEndDay.DayOfWeek <> 0
    pEndDay = pEndDay.AddDays(1)
End While
```

i'd like to translate it to C#.

in vb.net i can compare the DayOfWeek with an integer.
In c# this seems not to be possible.

i can only compare it with the enum itself.

For example:

```
        while (endDay.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {

        }
```

Now i'm not sure which DayOfWeek is 0 and which is 1.
0 could be monday or sunday probably.

1 could be monday or tuesday or whatever..

could anybody help me and tell me how to find out which enum position of DayOfWeek is 0 and which is one?

Comment: convert from vb.net to vb.net?

Comment: If only it were [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek(v=vs.110).aspx): "If cast to an integer, its value ranges from zero (which indicates `DayOfWeek.Sunday`) to six (which indicates `DayOfWeek.Saturday`)."

Comment: Another option is check original source code. [System.DayOfWeek](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/dayofweek.cs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer the part of your question:

> Now i'm not sure which DayOfWeek is 0 and which is 1 ...

From [the MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx)

> ... The value of the constants in this enumeration ranges from `DayOfWeek.Sunday` to `DayOfWeek.Saturday`. If cast to an integer, its value ranges from zero (which indicates `DayOfWeek.Sunday`) to six (which indicates `DayOfWeek.Saturday`).

And that's kindof the point of using an enum to begin with.  You should just stick with the code you showed:

```
while (endDay.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can cast the enum to an integer to achieve this.

```
 while ((int)pStartDay.DayOfWeek != 1)

 Console.WriteLine("Day 0 is: " + (DayOfWeek)0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while (pStartDay.DayOfWeek != 1) {
    pStartDay = pStartDay.AddDays(-1);
}

while (pEndDay.DayOfWeek != 0) {
    pEndDay = pEndDay.AddDays(1);
}
```

Comment: OP doesn't want to just translate the code. The question is about the `DayOfWeek` enum...